# How do I modify the title of a paper I submitted to ArXiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv, errors-erratum

I submitted a paper to the ArXiv, but after it has already been announced, I realized that there is a typo in the title (nothing catastrophic, but still..)

Do you have any idea how to slightly modify the title?

Answer (score 15):

*Short answer*: I believe the only way is to submit a revision.

*Long answer*: As per [this page](https://arxiv.org/help/replace):

## It is not possible to make changes without generating a new version

Why? To allow authors to make changes to the comments and other metadata fields of publicly announced articles without generating a new version, and hence date stamp, would effectively mean that all changes would be backdated to the time the last version was submitted. This is open to abuse and thus not allowed.

The ***exceptions to this rule are the addition of journal reference and DOI information***. The journal reference field may contain only full publication information for the article; the DOI field may contain only a DOI.

---

*My suggestion*: Although this replacement process would not be time consuming, it would be quite redundant and generate a new version of the paper. Since that would anyway happen whenever you revise your paper (say, after you incorporate the comments of referees), I would suggest -- *under the assumption that the typo does not look **glaringly bad*** -- to wait until you have a next version ready.

Comment: This is good information.  However, I am someone who thinks any spelling error, especially in a title, looks glaringly bad (or at least distracting).  Personally, I would go ahead and submit a revision (arXiv uses the term "replace").  Sure, your paper will become "v2" and generate another line in the daily mailing, and people will be able to see the original version if they really want, but I don't see that as a problem.  If you write in the comment field "fix typo in title" then people who have already read it will know that they don't need to pay attention.

Comment: Actually my typo is not awfully bad - since me and the coauthor use a different style (British vs. American spelling), the title and the rest of the text are in two styles. I don't think everybody will even notice, but i would prefer it to be correct. I guess it is best to wait for the revised text and just change all the text to fit the title :)